# Unable to connect to a websocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, websocket, stunnel

I created a PHP websocket using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). This Websocket is running on port `8080` of my internal server `10.0.4.160`.

I am trying to connect to it from a website that have SSL enabled "aka using https protocol."

When attempting to connect to the websocket form a FireFox browser, I get security issues from the browser because I am mixing between secured/non-secured connection. This is the error that I see in the javascript's console.

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

To fix the security issue I created a [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) proxy which allows me to accept the connection on  `10.0.4.160:58443` and connect it to port `127.0.0.1:8080`. This secure tunnel should allow me to keep my connection to the websocket secured and bypass the browser's security check.

However, every time I attempt to connect to the websocket I get an error

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://10.0.4.160:58443/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

This is the jQuery script that is used to connect to the websocket

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {
            var conn = new WebSocket('wss://10.0.4.160:58443');

            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");
                showMessage('Connected', 0);
            };

            conn.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log(e.data);
                showMessage(e.data, 1);
            };

            conn.onclose = function(e) {
                console.log(e.code);
                console.log(e.reason);
            };              

            conn.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            };      

        } else {
            console.log('Your browser does not support Websocket!');
        }

        function showMessage(msg, append){
            if(append){
                $('#status').append('<br>' + msg);
                return;
            }

            $('#status').text(msg);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is my current stunnel configuration

```
[websockets]
client = yes
accept = 58443
connect = 8080
verify = 2
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
debug = 7
OCSPaia = yes
```

How can I connect to the websocket from my browser?
Thank you

Comment: Down voted until we see your PHP server set up with ratchet

Answer (score 1):

read more about html5 websockets at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Socket.io is a popular web socket library read more at www.socket.io

There is not enough information to diagnose your issue. Please provide a server log.

- Does your server recognize a connection attempt?
- Does your server
  handle the client server handshake?

If your server recognizes a connection attempt then your issue is more than likely the handshake. There is not an issue with your JavaScript.

---

**EXTRA INFORMATION:**

another type of connection: (we will call this type 1)

```
|SERVER(PHP)| <--- CONNECTION --> |SERVER(websocket)|
```

what you are using: (we will call this type 2)

```
|BROWSER(client)| <----CONNECTION --> |SERVER(websocket)|
```

when using **type 1** connections as **type 2** connections you risk overflowing your main web server which will cause sever performance issues. Web host like: Godaddy, Hostgator.. ect.. will terminate connections that are flooding their servers because they are seen as DDOS attacks.

I dont know what ratchet is, but to keep a server & client connection open PHP will need to stay open & this is NEVER NEVER NEVER EVER EVER a good idea. Look into created a server in languages such as C# or C++.